# How to get data from excel into soap requests

Tags: soapui

I am able to create the data source in soap ui pro and am using data driven testing by pulling rows from Excel and executing responses. What i want is, i want to read 1 row from excel and input in different requests instead of using different data in same test.For example I want row 1 data goes to request1 and row2 data to request2. I think I need groovy script for it or if this can be done in ready api?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1 :**
Go to DataSource and in the step details you will see settings icon. Click on that
[view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px68V.png)

**Step 2 :** 
Specify the desired amount of rows in the Rows per Iteration box as 2 .
[view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfeKl.png)

**Step 3 :**
Go to your first Request and in the field value, add something like this
${DataSouceTestStep#DataSourceProperty::RowNumber}
[view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLa2b.png)

For example in my scenario, i need to send party id from first row to first request and my datasource name is "DataSource" and Column which i want to send from row is "PARTY_ID", so i would form my expression as follows :

${DataSource#PARTY_ID::0}

**Step 4 :**

Go to second request and as you want to send data from second row i would form my expression as follows :

${DataSource#PARTY_ID::1}

Let me know if you need any further help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very standard, so you will need to change your approach slightly:

1. Create a counter, set it to zero.
2. Create a Data Source step for your Excel.
3. Increment the counter.
4. Based on the counter, set value in either the appropriate request step, or some property.
5. Loop back to 2.
6. All your requests go here.